# "Welcome back [object Object] you've been logged in" when changing sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, login

I switched from Stack Overflow to meta and saw this:

> [image]

Welcome back `object Object`?? Do I see an unhandled situation here?

Comment: Happens for me too when I visit a SE site where I am not logged in.

Comment: I object to this bug!

Comment: not if your name is `[object Object]`

Comment: Talk about objectifying your users. Sheesh.

Comment: Can you tell it is Friday in SE hq?

Comment: Probably localisation. It always is localisation.

Comment: localization and omg how do I test this without going live

Comment: All objects extend Object by default,  you're just rejecting your true nature

Comment: I thought it's always caching?!

Comment: @juergend - localization is the new caching

Comment: Can't reproduce, it's an object of your imagination.

Comment: it's objectively annoying, though

Comment: [meta-tag:status-bydesign]

Comment: ​​​​​​​​`''+{}`

Comment: @Oded it is *always* Friday in SE hq

Comment: Totally changing my name to [object Object] ♦

Comment: @TinyTim Unfortunately, brackets aren't allowed in names. (I tried it.)

Comment: Stack Exchange uses Objective-C?

Comment: @michaelb958 we should fix that with some Unicode hackery.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Fixed in build `2013.11.29.1696` on meta and `2013.11.29.1183` on sites.

Comment: That was quick!

Comment: "Fixed in build [object Object] on meta and [object Object] on sites" you say?

Comment: I object to that...