# Stack Overflow knows I am a robot and greets me in robot language

Tags: bug, status-completed, captcha

Because of a slightly flakey connection, I **think** I was just prompted to prove I am a human when trying to post an answer.

However, although the dialog box popped up and the rest of the page was masked with an overlay, instead of the Flights of the Concords screenshot and the captcha prompt, the dialog box consisted *only* of the immortal text `[object Object]`.

I think this means Stack Overflow is on to me and **knows** I am not human, and is trying to talk to me in Robot language, a silent little language only Robots can understand<sup>*</sup>.

Sorry, no screenshot. I was a little flustered at being called out like that.

<sup>*<sub>With apologies to [Tomten](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=L4TjDAAAQBAJ&lpg=PT15&ots=7mXaX4dD4z&dq=tomten%20talk%20to%20them%20in%20tomten%20language%2C%20a%20silent%20little%20language&pg=PT15#v=onepage&q=tomten%20talk%20to%20them%20in%20tomten%20language,%20a%20silent%20little%20language&f=false)</sub></sup>

Update: Martin Smith provided one:

[image: Robot robot]

and I reproduced it the same way (paste into the sandbox and <kbd>TAB</kbd> then <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to post something fast to see the error:

[image: JS exception]

I'm using Chrome 31 on OS X.

Comment: Well it's about time :D

Comment: Well, people have objected to objects which may be related [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209366/welcome-back-object-object-youve-been-logged-in-when-changing-sites)

Comment: Reproduced [Screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0JK8S.png). It is easy to get the captcha to appear by going to the sandbox question and posting an answer by pasting in some content then submitting immediately.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I did link the screenshot? The URL is `http://i.stack.imgur.com/0JK8S.png` I pasted the content of your question here though so maybe that is the confusion. JS Console shows an error in "recaptcha_ajax.js"

Comment: I probably mis-tapped the comment link instead (on my smartphone). Thanks for the screenshot, @Martin!

Comment: Stack Overflow simply finally recognizes that all Marti?ns are Robots. Feature not bug.

Comment: That regex of yours would explain why Martin and Martn would have @pro​blems, but not Martijn, Pekka. ;-)

Comment: @Arjan: that's a glob pattern instead :-)

Comment: [I doubt that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188892/glob-pattern-matching-in-net), Martijn ;-)

Comment: 01010111 01100101 01101100 01100011 01101111 01101101 01100101 00100000 01101000 01101111 01101101 01100101

Comment: @apaul34208: 01010100 01101000 01100001 01101110 01101011 01110011 00100001 00100000 01001001 00100000 01100001 01110000 01110000 01110010 01100101 01100011 01101001 01100001 01110100 01100101 00100000 01110100 01101000 01100101 00100000 01110011 01100101 01101110 01110100 01101001 01101101 01100101 01101110 01110100 00101110 00100000 00111010 00101101 01010000

Comment: What is your browser (you only said smartphone, and only in comment, you should answer me by editing your post) ? Does it have restriction on cross-site javascript ? For example, if you have Firefox, you need to [whitelist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208814/242736) google.com, which is serving the captcha.

Comment: @user2987828: This is Chrome 31, on Mac OS X, no restrictions. This is a JS bug, it worked fine before.

Comment: Why oh why, Google Translate, I command you to humanise this unholy conversation at once!

Comment: Mods, I think @MartijnPieters just called you all stupid doody heads (and I'm sure my translator is working).

Comment: @Martijn Pieters. Its not isolated to OS X I got the same thing on Windows 7 using Chrome. I had the same type of poor connection.

Comment: 01000111
01110010
01100101
01100101
01110100
01101001
01101110
01100111
01110011
00100001
00100000
01001001
00100000
01000011
01101111
01101101
01100101
00100000
01101001
01101110
00100000
01110000
01100101
01100001
01100011
01100101

Comment: @Martin and Martijn: do you think it's related to timing, or is the captcha simply broken for everyone? (I guess we would have seen a lot of reports then, though at least [one other question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209513/unable-to-ask-question-on-stack-overflow) did pop up. If the captcha might be broken for everyone, then maybe the title should be a bit more alarming?)

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: e2 99 a9 e2 99 ac 20 20 53 68 6f 6f 74 20 74 6f 20 6b 69 6c 6c 3b 20 53 63 6f 74 74 79 2c 20 62 65 61 6d 20 6d 65 20 75 70 21 20 e2 99 aa e2 99 ac 20 54 68 65 72 65 27 73 20 4b 6c 69 6e 67 6f 6e 73 20 6f 6e 20 74 68 65 20 73 74 61 72 62 6f 61 72 64 20 62 6f 77 2c 0a 73 74 61 72 62 6f 61 72 64 20 62 6f 77 2c 20 73 74 61 72 62 6f 61 72 64 20 62 6f 77 2e 2e 2e 20 e2 99 aa e2 99 ab 0a

Comment: @Arjan: I don't know; all I know is that I can trigger it explicitly and that the error is reproducable.

Comment: @Martijn, 01000101011101100110010101110010011110010110111101101110011001010010000001101011011011100110111101110111011100110010000001110010011011110110001001101111011101000111001100100000011001000110111101101110001001110111010000100000011010000110000101110110011001010010000001110100011011110110111001100111011101010110010101110011001011100010111000101110

Comment: `data:text/plain;base64,Q291bGQgZXZlcnlvbmUgcGxlYXNlIHF1aXQgdGFsa2luZyBpbiBkaWZmZXJlbnQgYmFzZXMgYW5kIGVuY29kaW5ncz8gSXQncyB0ZXJyaWJseSBkaWZmaWN1bHQgdG8gdHJhbnNsYXRlLg==`

Comment: I exhausted all my comment upvotes today on a wonderful "conversation" going on here

Comment: Robots currently have the numbers "0" and "1" to provide a statistic and non-sensical statement: "Bleep, borp, blurr?" Stack Overflow can test you, because I believe it has Captcha.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The captcha was broken only in one of the places where it is used.

Fix is rolling out in the build - rev `[object Object].1698` on meta and `[object Object].1185` on sites.

Comment: ['c', 'o', 'o', 'l'].join('')!

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0"?><methodCall><methodName>stackexchange.issues.confirm</methodName><params><param><string>Fix confirmed, the CAPTCHA works as intended again. Thanks!</string></param></params></methodCall>`