# Unable to ask question on stack overflow

Tags: bug, new-users, spam-detection

I created a new user(this user). On my profile I can see that I have the right to ask questions.  I'm not sure if this was the case last night.

I tried to ask a question, but got a message back saying my question appears to be spam.  I don't think this is because of the structure of my question, the only reason I can think this was is because I had the wrong date on my machine.  I changed it to February for testing purposes.

This morning I tried to post the question again, with the correct date on my machine.  I get a popup, which I assume is an error message, I can't read it though because it only says

> object Object

Any ideas as to why this could be or what I can try to fix this?

Edit:
After trying to submit it a couple of times trying to catch the exception I'm getting the "Your question appears to be spam." error again. I assume this is because I've tried multiple times from the same IP/user?

The fact that I can post questions here tells me that the content of my question might actually be the problem, but without a clear indication as to what the problem is I'm a bit baffled. As far as I can see I'm following the template exactly.

Edit2: Here is the text of the question I'm trying to post(if it works here then I'm stumped):

> I'm using jsf 2.1 and I'm experiencing some problems with the h:link
>   tag.  I'm trying to have the link's outcome point from my xhtml file
>   to another html file.  However, when I run my web application, the
>   source is automatically converted to an xhtml extension.
>
> Here is my xhtml file:
>
> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
>   xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
>   xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
>   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
>
> <h:head>
>   <title>MyPage</title>
> </h:head>
>
> <h:body>
>   <h:form>        
>       <h:link value="animation" outcome="#{contentForm.ccAnimationLink}"/>            
>   </h:form>
> <h:body>
> ```
>
> Here is my contentForm bean:
>
> ```
> package my.app.content;
>
> import java.io.Serializable;
> import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
> import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
> import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
> import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
>
> @ManagedBean
> @RequestScoped
> public class ContentForm implements Serializable {
>   private static final long serialVersionUID = -8463354828156798513L; 
>   private String ccAnimationLink = "";    
>
>   @PostConstruct
>   public void init() {        
>       ccAnimationLink = "/content/cc/CC_animation/story.html";        
>   }
>
>   public String getCcAnimationLink() {
>       return ccAnimationLink;
>   }
>
>   public void setCcAnimationLink(String ccAnimationLink) {
>       this.ccAnimationLink = ccAnimationLink;
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Now, when I run this application, I get the following error:
>
> > Unable to find matching navigation case from view ID '/content/modifiedcc.xhtml' for outcome
> >     '/content/cc/CC_animation/story.html'
>
> I made sure that I had the url correct, so I created a story.xhtml
>   file in that location as well. With that file there it runs without
>   errors.
>
> If I pull the source for the generated page, I can see that the h:link
>   was correctly changed to an "a href" tag, as follows:
>
> ```
> <a href="/MyWebApp/content/cc/CC_animation/story.xhtml">animation</a>
> ```
>
> For some reason though the url change from story.**html**, like I have
>   it in my bean, to story.xhtml.
>
> How can I make sure that it stays as story.html and not change it to
>   xhtml?
>
> For what it's worth, here is my web.xml file as well:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
> ```
>
> xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
>   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
>   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID"
>   version="3.0">
>         MyWebApp
>         
>           javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE
>           Development
>         
>         
>           jsf/login/login.xhtml
>         
>         
>           Faces Servlet
>           javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
>           1
>         
>         
>           Faces Servlet
>           /faces/
>         
>         
>           *Faces Servlet*
>           .jsf
>         
>         
>           Faces Servlet
>           *.faces
>         
>         
>           Faces Servlet*
>           .xhtml
>
> I'm sure this has a very simple solution which I'm just missing right
>   now.  Help would be highly appreciated.  I hope the question is clear.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209460/172661

Comment: Could you post the text of the question?

Comment: So I can post it on this forum, but not where I'm supposed to post the question.

Comment: All I can think is that there are a lot of URLs, maybe that is tripping the spam filter?

Comment: Thanks @JohnPalmer, that was the problem.

Comment: @JohnPalmer post this as answer please, but I think that URLs inside code blocks should not affect the spam filter... bug report may be due.

Comment: Also, this is not a forum, it's a Q&A site.

Comment: The duplicate is unrelated. Voted to re-open.

Comment: @Yannis yep, that other report is about the "object Object" popup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the comments it appears that the spam filter was tripped by the large number of URLS

It is possible that this is a bug

Comment: Even if this isn't a bug, it desperately needs a more informative error message.

Comment: @Yannis I am pretty sure this one is supposed to display a captcha?

Comment: @Emracool Hm? Why? A captcha won't prevent _human_ spammers. There's a two-links-only limit for brand new users (less than 10 rep), and I think that's what stopped the post from going through.

Comment: @Yannis Ah, huh, didn't know about the link limit. Nevermind, then!

Comment: @Emracool It's part of the [new user restrictions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user). However, I'm not entirely sure those restrictions are to blame here. It's possible there's an additional anti-spam filter that works the same for all users, regardless of rep.

Comment: @Yannis Fair. I have encountered a topic I don't know about, so it is my time to bow out. Looking through this, though; thanks!